# How to implement a fractional polynomial transformation in R for logistic regression

Tags: r, regression, logistic, modeling, fractional-polynomial

I'm working on a data set modeling road kills (0 = random point, 1 = road kill) as a function of a number of habitat variables.  Following Hosmer and Lemeshow, I've examined each continuous predictor variable for linearity, and a couple appear nonlinear.  I'd like to try a fractional polynomial transformation for each, also following Hosmer and Lemeshow, and have looked at the R package mfp, but I'm having trouble coming up with (and understanding) the R code that will correctly transform the variable.  Can anyone suggest R code that would help me accomplish the concepts on p. 101 - 102 of Hosmer and Lemeshow's Applied Logistic Regression (2000).

Answer (score 2):

Here is some R code with an example taken from an example data set included in package `MASS`:

```
library(MASS)
library(mfp)
data(birthwt)

vignette("mfp_vignette",package="mfp")   # Read this!

mfp_mod <- mfp(factor(low) ~ fp(age,df=4)+fp(lwt,df=4)+factor(race)+factor(smoke)+ptl+factor(ht)+factor(ui)+ftv, family=binomial,data=birthwt)

summary(mfp_mod)
```

(I did not include output).  An alternative would be to use splines.